# How to solve first order non-linear ODE $y'=\frac{2x+y+4}{4x-2y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I can solve first order non-linear ODE like below:
$$y'=\frac{2x+y+4}{4x+2y}$$
This is quite easy by substituting $2x+y$ with $u$. However, I have tried to solve the differential equation as title:
$$y'=\frac{2x+y+4}{4x-2y}$$
Note that the denominator has the negative sign $4x-2y%$. It seems that neither substituting nor setting $v=\frac{y}{x}$ is working. Please help me with the detailed answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In this case let $x=u+\alpha$ and $y=v+\beta$ with substitution obtain suit $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to equation be homogeneous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

In this case let $x=u+\alpha$ and $y=v+\beta$ with substitution obtain suit $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which equation to be homogeneous.
$$y'=\frac{2x+y+4}{4x-2y}$$
$$v'=\frac{2u+2\alpha+v+\beta+4}{4u+4\alpha-2v-2\beta}$$
\begin{cases}
2\alpha+\beta+4=0,\\
4\alpha-2\beta=0.
\end{cases}
$\alpha=-1$ and $\beta=-2$. so solve $$v'=\frac{2u+v}{4u-2v}$$

Comment: Why did you put $4\alpha-2\beta=0 $ and $2\alpha+\beta+4=0$. I don't understand it. Would you explain it?

Comment: The goal is vanishing two constants from numerator and denominator. here we have one constant $4$ in the numerator.